# An interesting integral $\int{\dfrac{x^m}{x^{2m}+1}dx}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I have, for a long period of time, tried to evaluate the indefinite integral $\int{\dfrac{x^m}{x^{2m}+1}dx}$ for different values of $m$, such as $m=2,3,4,6...$, and I have recently thought of generalizing this integral for all values of $m\in\mathbb{N}$. Since evaluating the integral using partial fractions for high values of $m$ by myself is very time consuming, and it happens that I can't find any direct solution on the internet, I tried to look for patterns of the integrals in WolframAlpha. After some comparisons, I found the below expression:
$$\int{\dfrac{x^m}{x^{2m}+1}dx}=\sum_{n=1}^{m}(-1)^{n-1}(\dfrac{1}{2m}\sin(\dfrac{(2n-1)\pi}{2m})\ln{|x^2+2\cos(\dfrac{(2n-1)\pi}{2m})x+1|}$$$$+\dfrac{1}{m}\arctan(\csc(\dfrac{(2n-1)\pi}{2m})(x+\cos(\dfrac{(2n-1)\pi}{2m})))\cos(\dfrac{(2n-1)\pi}{2m}))$$
How could I have found the above expression without comparing the integrals?

P.S. It seems that the equivalence $x^{2m}-2x^ma^m\cos(m\theta)+a^{2m}\equiv\displaystyle\prod_{r=0}^{m-1}(x^2-2ax\cos(\theta+\dfrac{2r\pi}{m})+a^2)$ for $a\in\mathbb{R}^+, \theta\in\mathbb{R}, m\in\mathbb{N}$ can be used, yet I don't know how I can evaluate partial fractions with it.

Comment: [A duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1998618/factoring-x2n1-to-evaluate-int-tanx1-ndx), but the answer there might not be the best.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/784805/629362) seems to have what you want.

Comment: @ArcticChar Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Wolfram Mathematica gives this result $$\int \frac{x^m}{x^{2 m}+1} \, dx=\frac{x^{m+1} \, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{m+1}{2 m};\frac{1}{2} \left(3+\frac{1}{m}\right);-x^{2 m}\right)}{m+1}$$ where $2F_1$ is explained here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#The_hypergeometric_series

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Factorize $x^{2n}+1= \prod_{k=1}^{2n}(x-x_k)$ with $x_k= e^{i a_k},\>a_k=\frac{(2k-1)\pi}{2n}$. Then
$$\frac{x^n}{x^{2n}+1}=-\frac1{2n}\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{x_k^{n+1}}{x-x_k}$$
and integrate
\begin{align}
&\int \frac{x^n}{x^{2n}+1}dx \\=& -\frac1{2n}\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\int \frac{x_k^{n+1}}{x-x_k} dx 
= -\frac1{2n}\sum_{k=1}^{2n} x_k^{n+1} \ln(x-x_k)\\
= &-\frac1{2n} \sum_{k=1}^{2n} [\cos(n+1)a_k +i \sin(n+1)a_k]
\ln(x-\cos a_k -i\sin a_k)\\
= &-\frac1{4n} \sum_{k=1}^{2n} \cos(n+1)a_k \ln(x^2-2x\cos a_k+1)+2\sin(n+1)a_k \tan^{-1}\frac{\sin a_k}{x-\cos a_k} 
\end{align}

where only the real part survives.